# Want to use a map widget with Ozone Widget Framework (OWF)

Tags: widget

I have written some widgets for OWF.  They work well and I can easily send and receive intents and I can send messages on channels.  That's great.

I can also send Intents and messages for the CMAPI (Common Map API) which is supposed to be the standard way of saying, "please draw this on a map".

The only thing I *can't* do is find an implementation of CMAPI.  It's wonderful that there is a standard for interacting with maps, but has anyone tried to implement it before?

I did find the ESRI OWF widgets called Esri-Ozone-Map-Widget on github.  That's cool and sounds like exactly what I want, except it says:

> CMWAPI map.feature.plot messages are not supported by the map widget

What good is a map widget if you can't plot features on it?  I have no idea.  If I were implementing a map widget, the first thing I would work on is map.feature.plot.  But I'm not a GIS expert.  Maybe there are many things people want to do with maps other than plotting features on them.

I also found Boeing Meridian project.  That works great and allows me to open a map as a widget.  It claims that it responds to CMAPI intents but I was never able to get that working.

Is there anything else?  Surely someone has thought, "hey, let's try using maps to display geospatial data within OWF"?  I can't be the first one to consider this idea...

There is a simple Google Maps widget that comes with it as a demo, but it *only* supports plot.  I can't even remove a marker after I have plotted it.  It's not for any serious use.

Comment: CMAPI is a spec, by the NGA. Standards groups believe in documentation (not code) as a product. Implementations usually depend on someone funding the work. If the NGA didn't fund something, it probably didn't happen. My guess is another year or three (once the spec settles down) it might start appearing in mass-market products. Otherwise, maybe you could do an implementation?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I won't use CMAPI in that case.  Which map widget do you recommend then for a simple use to display some markers?  The example Google map is too limited.  I'm not sure what else people are using?  Thank you